# Access value through index number from ansible gather facts variable

Tags: ansible

I am using gather fact variable to get size information about host. for some server I am getting variable `"ansible_devices": { "sda"` and for few server getting `"ansible_devices": { "cciss!c0d0"`.

**Problem:-** When I am using variable `{{ ansible_devices.sda.size }}` in my playbook and if `sda` key not found in `ansible_device` variable then obviously it gives me error

```
fatal: [xyz101] =>One or more undefined variables: dict object has no element sda
```

Getting value in `ansible_device` [variable](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts) like below

```
     "ansible_devices": {
            "sda": {
                "size": "68.33 GB",
                ........
              }
        },
        "item": ""
```

or

```
     "ansible_devices": {
            "cciss!c0d0": {
                "size": "68.33 GB",
                ........
              }
        },
        "item": ""
```

Also I can access size here using `{{ ansible_devices.sda.size }}` in first case But unable to fetch value in `{{ ansible_devices.cciss!c0d0.size }}` in second case.

It might be the case special character in a json key that's why I am unable to fetch its value.

Is there any way to access this variable through key index `{{ ansible_devices[0].size }}` ?
or any other better way to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can check key by using `has_key` in ansible playbook like below.

```
when: ansible_devices.has_key('sda')
```

Above check resolve my fetal error as I have added two task for these two keys. But still I am looking the solution where I can get these key value through index number. It will replace multiple condition into one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a conditional?

`when: ansible_devices.sda exists`

Or you can iterate through ansible_devices.keys() and with_items.

Comment: Thanks for solution. Getting error msg : `error while evaluating conditional: ansible_devices.sda exists`